# Adjacency List HashMap<String, ArrayList<Edge>> failing to locate its values

Tags: java, hashmap, breadth-first-search

I am halfway through debugging a Breadth-First Search algorithm using an adjacency list representation of graph data: `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Edge>>`. Each String key is the name of an underground station, and each ArrayList is  a list of the edges for that station.

I am using a queue to store nodes of the graph in the order they are traversed. So I inspect the next in the queue for it's child's name. I then *want* to get the child's ArrayList of edges from the adjacencyList by using something like `childEdges = stationsAdjacencyList.get(childNodeName);`.

My syntax is a little different, but please check the code below.

At the moment the .get() function is not returning an ArrayList but is returning `null` every time instead. I know that the HashMap lookup is receiving the correct Key. It is just refusing to give me any value from it's associated bucket.

```
    while (!q.empty()) {    // 

        String endpointName; // the Key part for the next node lookup 

        // get next node (single entry of adjacency list)
        Map<String, ArrayList<Edge>> currentNode = (Map<String, ArrayList<Edge>>) q.deque(); 

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Edge>> nextNode = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Edge>>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Edge>> node : currentNode.entrySet()) { // there is only one node

            ++levelCount; // next node iteration is one level down the tree

            for (Edge edge : node.getValue()) {  // for each of this nodes Edges

                endpointName = edge.getEndpoint(); // retrieve the name of adjacent

                if (!endpointName.equals(destination)) { // if it's not the destination



                    levelTracker.put(edge.getParent(), levelCount); // record the level in the tree of this node

                    ArrayList<Edge> nextNodeEdges = adjacencyList.get(endpointName);

                    nextNode.put(endpointName, nextNodeEdges); // create child node from endpoint

                    q.enqueue(nextNode); // add child to queue

                }
                else if (endpointName.equals(destination)) { // if we're done

                    path.add(endpointName); // record the destination in the path (reverse order)

                    getPathBack(edge, levelCount + 1); // + 1 levelCount to indicate destination level in tree 

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Apologies if the code is not so clean or with decent comments, it is changing constantly. Hopefully someone can tell me why the `ArrayList<Edge> nextNodeEdges = adjacencyList.get(endpointName);` is not fetching anything.

Thanks!!

Comment: Where are you defining `adjacencyList`, or is that supposed to be `q`?

Comment: Also you have an error here: `endpointName == destination` (it's an invalid string comparison).  Besides that, you don't need to stipulate the `if` in the `else if` since if it's false those things are not equal, then they are equal, so the check for equality isredundant.

Comment: `adjacencyList` is defined earlier up, it is not the queue. The `adjacencyList` is comprised of String->EdgeList pairs. Each of these can be placed onto a queue one at a time, and removed one at a time. I am then looping through each of it's Edges.

Comment: So just as a test, can you retrieve a non-null set of edges outside of the mechanism shown here? (have you proven to yourself the adjacency list is in fact non-empty?)

Comment: Yes, noticed I hadn't got that bit fixed. Is fixed now. : )

Comment: I tested the `adjacencyList` and it works fine for `.get()` outside the `while (!q.empty())` loop.

Comment: Then all that's left is `endpointName` -- is it non-null and a valid value?

Comment: endpointName isn't null, it has the correct value. Frustrating.

Comment: Yes you were right, the endpointName needing trimming of a whitespace character in order for it to work. All fine now, thanks!

Comment: for completeness I'm going to repost my "solution" to the problem as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a good test is to see if calling `adjacencyList.get("valid endpoint");` in the same spot with a hardcoded value will return a non-null list. If it doesn't then `adjacencyList` is getting destroyed somewhere, if it does then `endpointName` isn't as correct as you think it is.